# Modify multiple formulas in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I already found the answer how to ADD characters to existing formulas. Here I add "/1000" in the end of the existing formulas in a range O31:R36.

```
Sub formatCells()
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Comparison").Range("O31:R36")
        cell.Formula = cell.Formula & "/1000"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

The problem arises when I try to make a macro to undo the changes. I try to use SendKeys method but with bad results. This block of code opens Object Browser in VBA when I wanted to simulate pressing F2 in Excel worksheet. So how could I get it to send keys to the worksheet? I'm using Excel 2010.

```
Sub unFormatCells()
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Comparison").Range("O31:R36")
        ActiveCell.Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        ActiveCell.Application.SendKeys "{BS 5}"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You simply cannot use the undo-command on anything you did with VBA.

Comment: You can't do it like that. You have to modify the formula string itself.

Comment: I know that I can't undo anything done with VBA. That's exactly the reason I want to create a macro that sets the formulas back as they were, just in case.

@serakfalcon, how could I then get access to the formula string?

Comment: You could just reverse your `formatCells` UDF (i.e. change `cell.Formula = cell.Formula & "/1000"` to `Cell.Formula = Replace(Cell.Formula, "/1000", "")`. Saying that, I would capture the range in an array, change the values in the array and then transpose them back to the range

Comment: If you want to program your own Undo-logic, what do you want to achieve with the SendKeys?

Comment: @Zac Thanks a million, exactly what I was looking for! Although now I feel a bit stupid since I didn't come up with that myself...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
Sub unFormatCells()    
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Comparison").Range("O31:R36")
         cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "/1000", "")
         cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Next cell
End sub
```